How to run Matter bridge on Android
I'm a newbie to Matter, I need to plug my Zigbee device into Matter now, on Linux, I successfully used the Zigbee Gateway and MatterBridge example to plug an OnOff over Zigbee into Matter, and I look at it in Apple Home.
Now, I need to port it all to my Android device, I don't know how Android works, I roughly searched: How to use an android device as a matter sensor?
Is there an example of running a Matter Device/Bridge instead of a Matter Controller on Android
Thanks！
